# Pyinstaller renders Wxpython GUI buttons and staticline colors differently on other computers

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, pyinstaller, exe

My issue isimilar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67151244/how-to-import-the-modules-you-need-when-converting-python-code-to-exe) but the answer did not solve it.

My problem is my  pyinstaller build renders my Wxpython GUI buttons and staticline colors differently on other computers.

**Here is the button and static line on the source computer:**

**Before hover:**

[image: bh]

**On hover:**

[image: oh]

**And here it is on another computer:**

**Before hover:**

[image: bn1]

**On hover:**

[image: oh1]

As you can see the button and lines are not the same colors.

How to get the same static line and buton colors output as the source one on every computers?

The source pc's specs:

```
Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
python 3.9.12 
pyinstaller 5.13.0 
wxPython-4.2.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

**The sequence I used to build the pyinstaller output:**

```
cd /c/testwxpython
    python -m venv virt
    source virt/Scripts/activate
    pip install wxPython
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    pip install pyinstaller

    pyinstaller --name myapp --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico --add-data "YouthTouchDemoRegular-4VwY.ttf;." sample_one.py
```

**Here is the Git bash terminal output:**

```
(virt)
GitT MINGW64 /c/testwxpython
$ pyinstaller --name myapp --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico --add-data "YouthTouchDemoRegular-4VwY.ttf;." sample_one.py
248 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.13.1
248 INFO: Python: 3.9.12
255 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
256 INFO: wrote C:\testwxpython\myapp.spec
260 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\testwxpython']
575 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
575 INFO: checking Analysis
586 INFO: Building because C:\testwxpython\sample_one.py changed
586 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
588 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
600 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1574 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
2022 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
2425 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3285 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3388 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3390 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Python39\python.exe
3452 INFO: Analyzing C:\testwxpython\sample_one.py
3494 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3617 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4258 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4543 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\_pyinstaller'...
5098 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5226 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5847 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6515 INFO: Processing module hooks...
6560 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
6588 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
6590 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
6592 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
6593 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
6601 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
C:\testwxpython\virt\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py:167: UserWarning: The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.
  __import__(package)
438 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): ['C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs']
438 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): ['C', 'C:\\testwxpython\\virt\\Scripts', 'C:\\Users\\Head Rule\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\user\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\Go\\bin\\go.exe', 'C:\\Windows\\System32', 'C:\\Go\\bin', 'C:\\Python39\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\Scripts', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Intel\\Shared Libraries\\redist\\intel64\\compiler', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH', 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\dotnet', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\ffmpeg-5.0-essentials_build\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\Tools\\Binn', 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\Tools\\Binn', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\DTS\\Binn', 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\DTS\\Binn', 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio', 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32', 'C:\\Go\\bin', 'C:\\Go\\bin\\go.exe', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'C:\\Users\\user\\.dotnet\\tools', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_pax3n2kfra5q2\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python39', 'C:\\Python39\\Scripts', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\vendor_perl', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\core_perl']
8127 INFO: Looking for eggs
8128 INFO: Using Python library C:\Python39\python39.dll
8128 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
8133 INFO: Warnings written to C:\testwxpython\build\myapp\warn-myapp.txt
8175 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\testwxpython\build\myapp\xref-myapp.html
8184 INFO: checking PYZ
8200 INFO: checking PKG
8206 INFO: Building because toc changed
8207 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) myapp.pkg
15082 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) myapp.pkg completed successfully.
15084 INFO: Bootloader C:\testwxpython\virt\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\runw.exe
15084 INFO: checking EXE
15084 INFO: Rebuilding EXE-00.toc because myapp.exe missing
15084 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
15085 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\testwxpython\dist\myapp.exe.notanexecutable
15114 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
15114 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\testwxpython\\icon.ico']
15138 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 20 bytes
15139 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 213032 bytes
15141 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
15141 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
15142 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\testwxpython\dist\myapp.exe.notanexecutable
15168 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
15170 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
15194 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
15843 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
(virt)
GitT MINGW64 /c/testwxpython
$
```

**Here is the output of the Build folder warn-myapp.txt file:**

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running your program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.
 
Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement
 
IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
            tracking down the missing module yourself. Thanks!
 
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional), importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), subprocess (optional), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named pyimod02_importers - imported by C:\Lulls\virt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py (delayed)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by getpass (optional), tty (top-level)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (optional)
missing module named _dummy_thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint (optional)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.ufunc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ones - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.hstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_1d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_3d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.vstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.linspace - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.index_tricks (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.transpose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.function_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.result_type - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.bool_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.inf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.array2string - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isscalar - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isinf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isnat - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ndarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.array_repr - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.arange - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.iinfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.twodim_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.reciprocal - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.argsort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isnan - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.count_nonzero - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.swapaxes - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.matmul - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.asanyarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_2d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.product - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.amax - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.amin - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.moveaxis - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.errstate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.finfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isfinite - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.sum - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.fastCopyAndTranspose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.multiply - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.dot - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.Inf - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.all - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.newaxis - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.empty_like - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.empty - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.zeros - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.asarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.array - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.core.numeric (delayed)
missing module named psutil - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, optional)
missing module named win32pdh - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, conditional)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named _ufunc - imported by numpy._typing (conditional)
missing module named numpy.bytes_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.str_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.void - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.object_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.datetime64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.timedelta64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.number - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.complexfloating - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.floating - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.integer - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.unsignedinteger - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.generic - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ufunc - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.float64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.float32 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.uint64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.uint32 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.uint16 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.uint8 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.int64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.int32 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.int16 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.int8 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named wx.GetMousePosition - imported by wx (top-level), rectshapedbitmapbuttonTwo (top-level)
missing module named StringIO - imported by six (conditional)
missing module named winxptheme - imported by wx.lib.agw.aui.dockart (conditional, optional), wx.lib.agw.aui.framemanager (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'Carbon.Appearance' - imported by wx.lib.agw.aui.aui_utilities (conditional, optional), wx.lib.agw.aui.tabart (conditional, optional)
missing module named winxpgui - imported by wx.lib.agw.artmanager (conditional, optional)
missing module named win32con - imported by wx.lib.agw.artmanager (conditional, optional)
missing module named win32api - imported by wx.lib.agw.artmanager (conditional, optional), wx.lib.agw.flatmenu (conditional, optional)
missing module named win32gui - imported by wx.lib.agw.flatmenu (conditional, optional)
missing module named UserDict - imported by wx.lib.agw.fmcustomizedlg (conditional)
missing module named Carbon - imported by wx.lib.colourutils (conditional, optional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
```

**Here is the myapp.spec output:**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
 
 
block_cipher = None
 
 
a = Analysis(
    ['sample_one.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('YouthTouchDemoRegular-4VwY.ttf', '.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
 
exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='myapp',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['icon.ico'],
)
```

I suspect my requirement file might be part of the reason for the issue because I can't account for it using Qt5 for my Wxpython app.

**Here is my requirement file:**

```
click==7.1.2
numpy==1.23.5
pandas==1.5.2
PyQt5==5.15.4
pyqt5-plugins==5.15.4.2.2
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.11.0
pyqt5-tools==5.15.4.3.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.21.0
pytz==2022.6
qt5-applications==5.15.2.2.2
qt5-tools==5.15.2.1.2
six==1.16.0
```

I couldn't find any other related problem question online and don't know what to test next to fix it.

Comment: I haven't used Windows in a decade (or 2) so I don't know but assume you can have different `themes` for the desktop. Are you running different `themes` on the computers you're testing?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony thanks for the remarks. I think they are the same, but the source is a VM. But I'll test the building asap on another PC to see if it makes a difference.